# ubiquity of free subgroups of special linear groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

I have a proof that if $n$ is an integer such that $n>1$ and $k$ is any field, then if $g$ is an element of $\mathrm{SL}(n,k)$ of infinite order then the set of all $h$ with the property that $g$ and $h$ generate a free group of rank two is Zariski dense.

http://rupertmccallum.com/free_groups.pdf

I am trying to find out if this result is already known. My former PhD supervisor Michael Cowling has said that it has appeared in a PhD thesis of Tal Poznansky, and I would like to contact Poznansky to see if I am saying anything new, or whether perhaps the method of argument is of some interest, but I have not been able to find Poznansky's email address on-line.

Does anyone know someone who is knowledgeable about results of this kind who might be able to tell me whether there is anything new here and whether the result is publishable?

Comment: Poznansky was a 2006 thesis student of Margulis at Yale but has not published anything (and is presumably not involved now in mathematics).   His thesis is listed on MathSciNet: *Existence of simultaneous ping-pong partners in linear groups.*  Thesis (Ph.D.)–Yale University. 2006. 48 pp. ISBN: 978-0542-65287-5. 
ProQuest LLC.   Perhaps Margulis could be helpful.  Also, various papers on free subgroups of linear groups have been published following the basic paper by Tits, e.g., R. Aoun, *Random subgroups of linear groups are free,* Duke Math. J. 160 (2011).

Comment: Poznansky posted one paper on arxiv including some relevant stuff: http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.2486

Comment: BTW Poznansky takes a lot of energy to find ping-pong partners not only in the ambient algebraic group, but in some given finitely generated Zariski dense subgroup therein. But as far as I remember, he does it only in some types of algebraic groups (AD or BC? I don't remember and the arxiv paper is hard to read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an interesting result with a cool method. By the way, you might want to look at Theorem 2 on page 158 of Borel's "On free subgroups of semisimple groups" (Enseign. Math. (2), 29(1-2):151–164, 1983). Using this and the Ping-Pong lemma, you can prove results that are similar (but not identical) to yours.

Comment: the existence a well as density/randomness results for free subgroups are well-understood; the typical difficulty here is to find a ping-pong partner for each given element of infinite order. The usual argument assumes the element $x$ is not virtually unipotent and finds a ping-pong partner for some power of $x$.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments. Gregory Soifer has advised me about a paper he wrote earlier with his student S. Vishkautsan, which would seem to cover the special case of what I am saying when the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$. It looks as though what I am saying is not really all that new.